# AudioKit Xcode 12 beta version

Tags: swift, audiokit, xcode12

Just downloaded Xcode 12 beta, and have tried to install the AudioKit framework, have set the 'other linker flags' to include '-lc++' and made sure the added framework was set to "embed and sign"

when I start an AudioKit main class:

```
import Foundation
import AudioKit
class AudioClass{

init() {
   // would normally start AudioKit/mixer/single instrument in here
}
}//end simple class
```

I get the following error message after I try to compile:

Failed to build module 'AudioKit' from its module interface; the compiler that produced it, 'Apple Swift version 5.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.1 clang-1103.0.32.29)', may have used features that aren't supported by this compiler, 'Apple Swift version 5.3 (swiftlang-1200.0.16.13 clang-1200.0.22.25)'
I.e something a version update will fix in time - does anybody know when AudioKit for Xcode 12/iOS 14 will be out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet with the Xcode 12 beta is to use the beta packages for AudioKit v5. These will support XCFrameworks via either CocoaPods or SwiftPM, which should not give you these errors.

You can find instructions for CocoaPods [here](https://github.com/AudioKit/Specs) (use version 5.0.b1 explicitly), and for SwiftPM [here](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKitSPM) (with the master branch).

Note that there's been some significant API changes so you probably will need to update your change. The biggest, most visible one is the `AKSettings` class renamed to `AKManager`.

Comment: I was having a bunch of random errors. I was using 4.9.5 and switching to 5.0b1 helped me compile in XCode 12 beta.

Comment: What happened to the Swift Package Manager Branch? The associated link is broken.

Comment: We've actually retired that SwiftPM repository as it's now part of the main AudioKit repository, albeit on the `v5-develop` branch. It's no longer a binary framework package, but rather a more traditional source package that should work with Xcode 11 as well.

Comment: @megastep will this branch build on XCode 12?

Comment: @theolll yes it will, we actually check that in the CI tasks at the moment.

Comment: Using AudioKit 5 doesn't work for me since it drops IAA support. I've solved this issue by upgrading Cocoapods to 1.10.0.rc.1